# Designing an app that consumes 2 Restful Web Services

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

using `RestKit` 0.2x, i want to build an iPhone app that will consume 2 different RESTful web services (two different base URLs):

- **web service A** will use Core Data to persist ~ 6000 objects in the persistent store.
- **web service B** will not use core data, it just will be mapped to regular `NSObject` subclasses, and also it will retrieve large set of objects (~1000 objects).

I decided to do the following design for the app:

**- in App Delegate:**

1) defining two different `RKObjectManagers` each with its own base URL.

2) setting up necessary object/entity mappings for each manager, along with request descriptors.

3) defining persistent store stuff using `RestKit`'s way.

**- in View Controllers:**

4) call the method `getObjectsAtPath` of `RKObjectManager` (for web service A) in the desired view controller inside a background thread (for ex. dispatch_async), i assume to use a background thread because the web service has thousands of objects to be retrieved, then using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to display this data on a `UITableView`.

5) call the method  `getObjectsAtPath` (for web service B) in a background thread in the desired view controller and display this data directly on a `UITableView`.

**my question:** is my design above correct or missing important steps ? if there is any missing stuff, would you please mention them ?

p.s. there is no `POST` methods involved with the web services, only `GET`, and the response is in `JSON` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup of the object managers sounds good and should work well.

When calling to get data, don't start the call from a background thread. RestKit does that for you. All of the download and mappings will be done on a background thread and then the result returned to the main thread for you.